# Horizontal Menu/List alignment issue

Tags: css, list, menu, alignment, styling

this is my first post to stackoverflow, but I use you guys knowledge constantly, so thanks!

I'm having an issue with menu alignment. I have a wordpress menu that I added divs inside the li element so that I could have a first/middle/last componant for each menu. This is so that I can have the current menu state raised up with the first and last items being "endcaps". Hard to explain, you can see it here: http://clarksvillevet.com/new/

Notice how the middle of the current menu item "sinks"? I cannot figure out what I'm missing here. I thought it was the line height, but that only moves it a bit. I'm guessing something is overlapping on the css (kinda calling it twice if you know what I mean), but again, no idea. Here is the HTML generated:

```
<div id="main-menu">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8">
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-23">
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="middle">
<a href="http://clarksvillevet.com/new/about-southside-va-veterinary-hospital/" title="About Southside Virginia’s Best Veterinary Hospital">About</a>
</div>
<div class="last"></div>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20">
<li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50">
<li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-56">
<li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-62">
</ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#main-menu{
width: 598px;
height: 51px;
margin: -6px 0px 0px;
z-index:401;
float: left;
background:url('images/BG-Menu.png') no-repeat top left transparent;
}

.menu {
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-image:none;
position:relative;
z-index:300;
width: 598px;
height: 51px;
float: left;
line-height: 57px;
}

.menu ul{
position:absolute;
line-height: 57px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
top: 51px;
left:0px;
display: none;
list-style-position:outside;
}

.menu a {
display:block;
display:inline-block;
padding:0px;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #dddddd;
margin: 0px;
}

.menu .first, .menu .middle, .menu .last {
position: relative;
padding:0px;
display: inline-block
}

.menu .first, .menu .last{
width: 11px;
height: 51px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.menu .middle {
height:51px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.menu a:hover {
color:#ffffff;
background-color:transparent;
}

.menu li {
float:left;
position:relative;
}


.menu ul a:hover {
color:#ffffff;
}

.menu li ul a {
width: 250px;
height: 32px;
float:left;
line-height: 30px;
background: url('images/BG-Drop-Menu.png') no-repeat top left transparent;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
color: #ffffff;
}

.menu li ul a:hover{
background: url('images/BG-Drop-Menu-Hover.png') no-repeat top left transparent;
}

.menu li ul ul {
left:0em;
margin:0px 0 0 10px;
}

.menu li:hover ul ul, .menu li:hover ul ul ul, .menu li:hover ul ul ul ul {
display:none;
}

.menu li:hover ul, .menu li li:hover ul, .menu li li li:hover ul, .menu li li li li:hover ul{
display:block;
}

.current-menu-item .first{
background:url('images/BG-Menu-Current-A.png') no-repeat top left transparent;
}

.current-menu-item .middle{
background:url('images/BG-Menu-Current-B.png') repeat-x top left transparent;
}

.current-menu-item .last{
background:url('images/BG-Menu-Current-C.png') no-repeat top left transparent;
}

.current-menu-item{
line-height: 51px;
}
```

There is also a dropdown menu, so when you see the .menu ul display:none , that is what its for... Feel free to correct any craziness you may see! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the child `divs` are inline-blocks. When this happens, line-height will be applied if it contains text. To fix this, you need to float the `divs` as done below.

```
.menu ul > div { float: left }
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep! I figured it out just a few minutes ago...and then came to tell everyone and saw your answer which is the EXACT solution. I didn't know about inline-blocks causing line-height application. Great to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you float both .first and .middle left (float: left;), this will solve the current problem.

But I feel your menu cutup suffers from more than just this issue. There's a couple of things to look at here:

- You have a .first .middle and .last. Why not just have a .first and .last, with your .last having a background image of .middle and .last combined? It will have to be a little longer to accommodate your other menu items, but that means only 2 images are loaded.
- Try to avoid empty divs, especially in your menu. This is an important section for both accessibility and SEO. You should spend time refining the markup of this section (probably) more than any other section of your site.
- Instead of using line heights (can get confusing when you're trying cross browser), try padding and margins.

Comment: Why didn't I think of the two divs instead of three!? Excellent. I've really never had any trouble using line height in the past (cross browser), its nice because it makes it easy to keep the text centered in the menu. I guess it's not a big deal to use padding/margins to achieve the same look, but its an efficiency thing.

OK, that stinks about the SEO thing. Any suggestions to achieve the same look? No jquery/javascript please.